# HTML Site that needs to be refreshing 24/7 2000+ requests a day

Tags: refresh

I have a wamp server setup with a single html file that will show a receipt along with some advertisement flash or images. I implamented live.js script to refresh the page evertime something in the receipt (pos program writes to the html file when order added) is changed. This worked great but when left idle it would take 30-60 seconds to respond and refresh again.

In my live.js file I edited the interval to .1 from 1000 and that made it alot more responsive. Is that okay performance wise.

What can I do to fix this issue? Is the browser closing the connection thus causing my issue? I reasearched keepAlive, is that what I need?

I also need an effecient method that wont crash or overload the wamp server or network connection.

For the javascript code its just the live.js from livejs.com I just changed the interval in the begining.

```
<html>                                    
<head>                                    
<script src="live.js"></script>           
</head>                                   
<body><pre>                               
Date:12/17/2014                           
Time:10:47 PM                             
Ticket No:221                             
------------------------------------------
- 1 Chicken Quesadilla                6.49
- 1 Saganaki (OPA!)                   5.49
- 1 Fried Mushrooms                   5.49
- 1 Appetizer Platter                 7.49

==========================================
Tax:                                  5.33
Total:                               94.19
==========================================
           T H A N K   Y O U             
</pre>                                    
</body>                                   
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: OK I did. Any Ideas @prady00

Comment: What about live.js ? Or creating a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/750fguxx/3/ @prady00

Comment: I think your usecase is different from the livejs intentions.
Livejs is used to save edits on web browser to server.
You should use a manual post of jquery and handle the post on server with some server side scripting language

Comment: Yeah okay, can you lead me in the right direction please?